# Boost::Asio C++ Why I`m getting the garbage while reading buffer?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I have a client which read file and sends the data to server line by line. Server must count the number of lines sent. I'm using `boost::asio::async_read_until` to reach this result. But I'm getting the garbage (like this: Line: `�68�`) when trying to read data from buffer. Client sends the data only in ASCII encoding.

Client code fragment:

```
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
      boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(line + '\n'));
      std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

Server read function:

```
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_trasferred, boost::asio::streambuf& buf)
    {
      if (!error)
    {
        if (!bytes_trasferred)
        {
            std::cout << "0 bytes trasferred\n";
            return;
        }

        std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
        std::istringstream is(data);
        std::string line;
        std::getline(is, line);
        std::cout << "Line: " << line << std::endl;    
    }
      else
        std::cerr << "Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        std::cout << "do_read\n";
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::streambuf buf;
        buf.prepare(1048576);
        std::cout << "ASYNC\n";
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, buf, "\n",
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::ref(buf)));
    }
```

How to resolve it? Help me, please!

I've  tried to use 'self' 'this' instead. It follows to memory leak.

I've tried to add null terminator after getting data in handler function. ChatGPT said me about this way, but behavior still same.

Comment: you're printing the whole buffer rather than just `bytes_trasferred` bytes? As `self` is not captured in your call to `async_read_until` it won't have its intended effect of keeping the current object alive

Answer (score 0):

1. Here:

   ```
   std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
   ```

   This is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as your are assuming that `buf.data()` points to a character sequence that is properly terminated with a NUL character, where you have absolutely no reason to assume this.
2. Besides you have UB because you pass a reference to `buf`, a local variable, which will by definition no longer be valid after `do_read` returns.
3. Thirdly, as Alan pointed out, you failed to copy the shared pointer (`self`) into the bound handler.

You're mixing many different ways to attack the problem of dealing with line-wise input. By far the easiest approach is to

- use a dynamic buffer (like indeed, `streambuf`)
- make it a member, because that's why you have `shared_from_this` in the first place
- do not use `prepare()` because `async_read_until` knows how to do that (just like it does `commit()` for you)
- **do** use `consume()` instead of doing `getline` /again/, even though `async_read_until` already tells you where the newline is.

Combining that:

```
struct TcpConnection : std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection> {
    TcpConnection(tcp::socket s) : socket_(std::move(s)) {}

    void run() {
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket     socket_;
    asio::streambuf buf;

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cerr << "handle_read: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            std::string const line(boost::asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data()), n);
            buf.consume(n);

            std::cout << "Line: " << quoted(line) << std::endl;
            do_read();
        }
    }

    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            socket_, buf, "\n",
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), asio::placeholders::error,
                        asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
};
```

I'd probably simplify, avoiding copying and potentially allocations:

```
struct TcpConnection : std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection> {
    TcpConnection(tcp::socket s) : socket_(std::move(s)) {}

    void run() {
        buf_.reserve(8192); // optional, tune to taste
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string buf_;

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cerr << "handle_read: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            auto line = std::string_view(buf_).substr(0, n);
            std::cout << "Line: " << quoted(line) << std::endl;
            buf_.erase(0, n);

            do_read();
        }
    }

    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf_), "\n",
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), ph::error,
                        ph::bytes_transferred));
    }
};
```

This still uses a dynamic buffer, but you don't have to do the extra hoops with `istream` which you apparently really don't need. For illustration purposes only, you could make the `dynamic_string_buffer` explicit:

```
    void run() {
        backing_.reserve(8192); // optional, tune to taste
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string backing_;
    asio::dynamic_string_buffer<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> buf_{backing_};

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cerr << "handle_read: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            auto line = std::string_view(backing_).substr(0, n);
            std::cout << "Line: " << quoted(line) << std::endl;
            buf_.consume(n); // look mom, it's a DynamiceBuffer all the same!

            do_read();
        }
    }

    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            socket_, buf_, "\n",
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), ph::error,
                        ph::bytes_transferred));
    }
```

Note, I wouldn't *do* that, but it demonstrates you how both approaches use the same `DynamicBuffer` concept as you did with `streambuf`.

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad82e984cbd1804)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ph = asio::placeholders;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct TcpConnection : std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnection> {
    TcpConnection(tcp::socket s) : socket_(std::move(s)) {}

    void run() {
        buf_.reserve(8192); // optional, tune to taste
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string buf_;

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t n) {
        if (n) {
            auto line = std::string_view(buf_).substr(0, n - 1); // exclude '\n'
            std::cout << socket_.remote_endpoint() << " Line: " << quoted(line) << std::endl;
            buf_.erase(0, n);
        }
        if (!ec)
            do_read();
        else
            std::cerr << "handle_read: n:" << n << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }

    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf_), "\n",
            boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), ph::error,
                        ph::bytes_transferred));
    }
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex) : acc(ex, {{}, 7878}) {}

    void start() {
        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    tcp::acceptor acc;

    void do_accept() {
        acc.async_accept(make_strand(acc.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::make_shared<TcpConnection>(std::move(s))->run();
                do_accept();
            }
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Server srv(ioc.get_executor());
    srv.start();

    ioc.run();
}
```

With the client emulated by a very similar oneliner:

```
netcat 127.0.0.1 7878 -w0 < main.cpp
```

Prints:

```
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "#include <boost/asio.hpp>"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "#include <iomanip>"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "#include <iostream>"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "namespace asio = boost::asio;"
...
...
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "int main() {"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "    asio::io_context ioc;"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: ""
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "    Server srv(ioc.get_executor());"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "    srv.start();"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: ""
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "    ioc.run();"
127.0.0.1:54860 Line: "}"
handle_read: n:0 End of file
```

Local demo showing multiple concurrent clients:

[image]